# Reading csv into array

Tags: c++, arrays, csv

I know the topic has been discussed a lot but I still don't really get it. Admittedly I am pretty new to C++ coding, so please go easy on me :)

Anyhow: I have this examplatory csv file:

```
    ,313,315
91.5919,1.44421,1.74019
91.592,1.44254,1.73816
91.5921,1.43859,1.73336
91.5922,1.43449,1.73109
```

I need an array with unknown dimensions a priori, since the csv will expand unpredictably -> dynamic array in both x and y direction.

This is what I managed to do so far:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<double> > values;
    vector<double> valueline;
    ifstream fin("in.csv");
    string item;
    for (string line; getline(fin, line); )
    {
        istringstream in(line);

        while (getline(in, item, ','))
        {
            valueline.push_back(atof(item.c_str()));
        }

        values.push_back(valueline);
        valueline.clear();
    }
}
```

It appears to be doing the job, but if I try to output the array or parts of it, I get strange results. For example     cout << values[0][3] << endl; yields 1.63042e-322. values[0][4] yields 91.5919. Also sizeof(values[0]) is 24.

Am I doing something I am not supposed to here?

Any help would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.at()` operator to see whether you aren't reading beyond the end of the vector? `values[0][3]` is the fourth element of the first line, which doesn't exist in your input?

You probably want to do:

```
std::cout << values[3][0]; // Fourth line, first element;
```

or

```
std::cout << values.at(3).at(0); // Fourth line, first element;
```

Index operators on vectors do not do bounds checking. This is for performance reasons. You are reading out of bounds, and thus you get the strange numbers. `at() throws a std::out_of_range exception.`

Answer (score 1):

Using `sizeof` on a vector is mostly useless -- it tells you the size of the top-level vector data structure (generally two `size_t`s and a pointer) in bytes, which is not terribly useful.  If you want the size of the vector, use the `size` method -- `values[0].size()` tells you how many values are on the first line.